# When condition not working metamug resource file

Tags: metamug

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Resource xmlns="http://xml.metamug.net/resource/1.0" v="1.0">
    <Request method="GET">
        <Desc> Example Resource </Desc>
       <Query when="x eq true"> 
          SELECT 'true'
         </Query>
      <Query when="x eq false"> 
          SELECT 'false'
      </Query>
    </Request>
</Resource>
```

When I'm sending the parameter x, the server is responding with `412 Precondition Failed` Error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `resource` file `when` attribute is used to execute [conditional queries](https://metamug.com/docs/resource-file.php#conditional-queries-with-when-). So a conditional expression is expected in `when` attribute.
In your case since you said you're sending `x` as parameter you need to write it this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Resource xmlns="http://xml.metamug.net/resource/1.0" v="1.0">
    <Request method="GET">
        <Desc> Example Resource </Desc>
       <Query when="$x eq true"> 
          SELECT 'true'
         </Query>
      <Query when="$x eq false"> 
          SELECT 'false'
      </Query>
    </Request>
</Resource>
```

Prefixing the variable with `$` identifies it as a `variable` if not then it is condisered as `String` literal which in that case you must enclose it withing quotes.
Ex.

```
<Query when="'x' eq false">
       //your query
    </Query>
```